# Are hardware locks resistant to port snooping?

Tags: locking

When I searched on the internet, I saw that there are ways to crack the hardware locks, which method is to listen to the connected ports and copy the information that is exchanged, and design a simulator that runs the program. turns

Is there a method or a specific protocol in these modern hardware locks that locks data between the sdk and the hardware lock and is resistant to this type of attack?

I saw that most of the companies provide the lock and software to the crackers to crack the lock. Is there a special software lock in the market that makes this connection safe?

I checked most of the products and did not see anything or explanation in their writings about whether there is a secure connection in these products that is resistant to the lock being copied.

For example, the following hardware lock production companies have been able to copy the lock by individuals or teams and have taken a copy of the lock:

Safenet Sentinel SuperPro UltraPro Rainbow, DESKey DK2 DK3, Eleckey
Eutron SmartKey, Feitian Rockey 2/4ND, GV-Series, Guardant, INROKey
KEYLOK 2, Marx CryptoBox, McAMOS SmartLock, MegaLock, Microcosm
Dinkey, Matrix, SENSELOCK Dongle, SG-Lock Dongle, SecuTech UNIKEY
SecureMetric SecureDongle X, Softlok, Wibu Codemeter CmStick Box Key